# Stream attachment should open in new window

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the code below to publish some link to a fan page:

```
$facebook->api (
    '/PAGE_ID/feed',
    'post',
    Array (
        'message' => '',
        'picture' => 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg',
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com/some/page.html',
        'name' => 'Some title'
    )
);
```

It works. The only problem is that if you click on the generated link on the fan page's wall (or in your stream) the page will open in the same window. I'd like for it to open in a new window.

I've searched the documentation but no mention of any parameter that would toggle this setting.

Comment: I don't think thats something you have control over. AFAIK external links to facebook should open in their own window. But I seem to have noticed that its not a very consistent thing on facebook in general.

Comment: Let that be a decision for the user. I hate it when web "masters" decide what's best for me.

Comment: @Emil I agree. But i just went to facebook and did a quick test. All the external links I tried on any page seemed to open in their own windows...

Comment: @Emil agreed. I was just wondering, since FB (by my expirience) opens all external links in new window and I was surprised that it's opening this links in the same window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and judging by the comments on my question, this can't be controlled.